# Editing ZipArchiveEntries (images) in memory

Tags: vb.net, gdi+, zip

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the code sample below.

I'm not getting any errors and the image looks like this after the compression is applied:

```
    Using _stm = _ZipArchiveEntry.Open
        Dim _ims = New MemoryStream
        Image.FromStream(_stm, True, True).Save(_ims, _codec, params)
        _stm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        _stm.SetLength(_ims.Length)
        _ims.CopyTo(_stm)
    End Using
```

[image: Corrupt image]

**NOTE**: If I write the image to disk it works though. I would like to avoid deleting and re-inserting zip archive entries though.

```
Using _stm = _ZipArchiveEntry.Open
    Image.FromStream(_stm, True, True).Save("C:\test.jpeg", _codec, params)
End Using
```

[image: Image written to disk]

Comment: Can you save the memory stream "_ims" to disk and compare the file with the one which you save directly in your second example?

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to reset the position on _ims back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to reset the "_ims" stream position back to 0. The sad part is, I assumed .CopyTo() would do this for me. So that was the last thing I actually checked...

This worked:

```
    Using _stm = p_ZipArchiveEntry.Open
        Using _ims As New MemoryStream
            Image.FromStream(_stm, True, True).Save(_ims, _codec, params)
            _stm.SetLength(_ims.Length)
            _stm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            _ims.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            _ims.CopyTo(_stm)
        End Using
    End Using
```